# MongoDB lookup with joining on field from $or

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have two collections, the first is friend_list, looks like this:

```
user_id: int
friend_id: int
status: string
```

And the second collection contains user data, looks like this:

```
user_id: int
username: string
etc.
```

I need to get all friend's user data for given user ID. The problem is, that this user can be friend_id or user_id, depends on who initiated a friendship. I came up with the request like this:

```
[
    [
      '$match' => [
        'friend_id' => $userId,
        'status' => ['$in' => [FriendStatus::ACTIVE, FriendStatus::PENDING]]
      ]
    ],
    [
      '$lookup' => [
        'from' => 'user_data', 
        'localField' => 'user_id', 
        'foreignField' => 'user_id', 
        'as' => 'user_data'
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

But instead of `'friend_id' => $userId` I need to use `'$or' => [['friend_id' => $userId], ['user_id' => $userId]]`. But this won't work with `'localField' => 'user_id'` in lookup.

I have the idea that this can be solved with `$group`, but I can not figure out how. 
Is there a way to $group user_id/friend_id field that does not equal to target user_id to a different field, that I can later use for lookup?

Comment: what is your mongodb version ? because what you are trying to do is only possible with the mongodb version 3.6 and above

Comment: My current version is 3.4.4, but there is possibility to update.

Comment: can you upgrade it to 3.6 or 4.0?

Comment: Yes, already working on it.